# Issue Saving Model from ViewMode/Viewl MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So what I want is when `SelectedModel.TechName` is updated that it physically saves to the model so that as long as the application is running it will remain whatever the user enters.

I have 2 views `SelectedModel.TechName` is called in both views. It pulls the data from the model however when I change views the data resets.

Any Suggestion?

edit: I am trying to make the data entered persistent, I thought setting the value would do this however every time i change between views it resets the data. In fact it blinks the data then resets it.

**Field from DefaultView.Xaml**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="5 5 5 0">
   <TextBox Name="techName" Text="{Binding SelectedModel.TechName,Mode=TwoWay}"  BorderBrush="#FF4A5780" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
</StackPanel>
<TextBlock x:Name="TextUpdate" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,0,0,0" 
Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedModel.TechName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

**DataModel.cs Model File**

```
namespace callFlow.Models
{
    public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            
        private string techName;

        public DataModel()
        {
        }

        public string TechName
        {
             get { return techName;  }
            set { techName = value; 
                  OnPropertyChanged();
                }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string techName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(techName));
        }
    }
}
```

**DefaultViewModel.cs**

```
namespace callFlow.ViewModels
{
       public class DefaultViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public DefaultViewModel() { }

        private ObservableCollection<DataModel> model = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();
        private DataModel selectedModel;
        private DataModel _SelectedModel;

        public DataModel SelectedModel
        {
            get { return _SelectedModel ?? (_SelectedModel = new SelectedModel()); }
            set { _SelectedModel = value; 
                   OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public void changeSelectedModel(DataModel newSelectedModel)
        {
            SelectedModel.TechName = newSelectedModel.TechName;

        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string techNameVM = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(techNameVM));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your binding you have

```
     UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit
```

in

```
   Text="{Binding SelectedModel.TechName,Mode=TwoWay, 
          UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
```

When you do that, you have to write code to update the source property. Which is the viewmodel property.
Since you don't do that, the viewmodel will not get updated when you type text in there.

You should either remove that off the binding or write some more code.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple potential issues in your code. First, you use `Explicit` as [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger?view=netcore-3.1), but you never call `UpdateSource`, at least you do not show that in your code. Consequently, the property will never be updated. Use `PropertyChanged` or `LostFocus` instead.

> If you set the UpdateSourceTrigger value to Explicit, you must call the UpdateSource method or the changes will not propagate back to the source.

Furthermore, you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your view models, but you never call `OnPropertyChanged`. Hence, bindings will never be updated when a property changes its value. Your properties should look like below. This applies to all properties that you expose.

```
public string TechName
{
   get { return techName;  }
   set
   {
      if (techName != value)
      {
         techName = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(); 
      }
   }
}
```

It is not clear how you create your views and set their `DataContext`. If you create the data context view model in the XAML of your view, it will be created each time you instantiate a new view.

Answer (score 1):

## Simple solution

Remove the `UpdateSourceTriger=Explicit` from your DefaultView.xaml

```xml
<TextBox Name="techName" Text="{Binding SelectedModel.TechName,Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="#FF4A5780" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

Call the `OnPropertyChanged` method in the `DataModel`.`TechName`'s setter. Like this:

```cs
public string TechName
{
    get { 
        return techName;  
    }
    set { 
        techName = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

## Better solution

There are a few problems with your code. Here's how to fix them:

#### DefaultView.xaml

Remove the `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`. It requires you to update the binding manually (from code) and you're not doing that.

```xml
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="5 5 5 0">
    <TextBox Name="techName" Text="{Binding SelectedModel.TechName,Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="#FF4A5780" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="TextUpdate" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,0,0,0" 
Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedModel.TechName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

#### DataModel.cs

You were not calling the `OnPropertyChanged` method in `TechName`'s setter, that's why it wasn't updating. I've done that and refactored the code a bit

```cs
public class DataModel : ObservableObject
{
    private string _techName;
    public string TechName
    {
        get => _techName;
        set { 
            _techName = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

#### DefaultViewModel.cs

Here I've just removed the empty default constructor, the extra private `DataModel` field and refactored the code.

```cs
public class DefaultViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataModel> Models = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();

    private DataModel _selectedModel;
    public DataModel SelectedModel
    {
        get => _selectedModel ?? (_selectedModel = new SelectedModel());
        set { 
            _selectedModel = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

#### INotifyPropertyChanged implementation - ObservableObject.cs

I've added this class to simplify the rest of the code, since you were using the same code in both DataModel.cs and DefaultViewModel.cs

```cs
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, However when  using OnPropertyChanged() and changing from Explicit i still have the same issue. The data isn't persistent. When i change from DefaultViewModel (Default View) to HomeViewModel(HomeView) the data resets to null. it saves while I am in the screen but goes away when I leave it.

Comment: @crapcoder could you add the `HomeViewModel` and `HomeView` code to your question?